# Is there a way to query the database before or during OnModelCreating?

Tags: entity-framework-core

Inside of `OnModelCreating`, I want to be able to ignore a column if the database is on an older migration EF Core 5 throws an exception if I attempt to read from the database directly, or indirectly by querying the applied migrations. I'm not certian that it's even a good idea, since `OnModelCreating` is used during the migration , but I'll burn that bridge when I cross it.

There are some examples on how one would do this with EF6, but they don't seem to apply anymore with EF Core.

Comment: I don' t see any problem. You can always use the good old Ado.net and text  sql queries

Comment: `OnModelCreating` is intended to build the latest model. The only intended conditionals are based on target database type, e.g. `Database.IsSqlServer()` etc. So no, it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [Ivan Stoev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202563/ivan-stoev) is right that --generally-- you should model the target database without outside input, the real world isn't always that clear-cut. In my particular case, there are multiple service instances (Azure Functions) that need to read and write to a single database. In order to maintain zero downtime, those Functions need to not read or write columns that don't yet exist.

I solved the problem the way [Serge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11392290/serge) suggested. The database has a known version, populated with [seed data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding) that increments with every migration. On startup, the service reads that version with a regular old `Microsoft.Data.Sql.SqlConnection`. This version is then added to the `IServiceCollection` as a singleton to be used by the `DbContext` constructor.

When talking to an older database version, `OnModelCreating` does things like this:

```
builder.Entity<Widget>(w =>
{
    // another option would be to use the migrations table instead of an integer
    if (DatabaseVersion < ContextVersions.WidgetNewPropertyAddedVersion)
    {
        w.Ignore(w => w.NewProperty);
    }
    else
    {
        w.Property(w => w.NewProperty)
            .HasDefaultValue(0);
    }
});
```

The startup code also detects if it's been started by the Entity Framework tools and *does not* read the database version, instead assuming "latest". This way, we do not ignore new properties when building the migration.

Figuring out how to let the service instances know that the database has been upgraded and they should restart to get the new database model is an exercise left up to the reader. :)